# Change css dynamically with window.resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any variant to change block width with `window.resize()`, if you have already set some rules?

Let's say I have a block with some width and get this width with JQuery:

```
var $block_1_width = $(".block_1").width();
```

I need to make another block have the same width, as the first one. So, i write:

```
var $block_2 = $(".block_2");

$block_2.css("width", $block_1_width + "px");
```

If I load the page, it will work fine, but I want them to dynamically keep the same size at any window width when user resizes the page. So, I try:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $block_2.css("width", $block_1_width + "px");
});
```

And it doesn't. I know that when I wrote `$block_2.css("width", $block_1_width + "px")`, JQuery set an inline style to `$block_2`. Does it mean that I cannot override it with `window.resize()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-calculate the `$block_1_width` after resize like so:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var $block_1_width = $(".block_1").width();
    $block_2.css("width", $block_1_width + "px");
});
```